# how can i display all posts where animal is dog using laravel

Tags: php, laravel, model-view-controller, methods, eloquent

i have 2 tables posts & animals withe a relation of one to may

posts table:
id,
animal_id

animals table:
id,
animal

---

Animal model:

```
public function posts()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Post::class);
}
```

Post model:

```
public function animale()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Animal::class);
}
```

faker:

```
  public function definition()
{
    return [
        'animal' => $this->faker->randomElement(['Dog', 'cat', 'fish']),

    ];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got a couple different ways to do this. You can either go via `Animal` model, or via the `Post` model:

Via `Animal.php` model:

```php
$posts = Animal::where('animal', 'Dog')->first()->posts;
```

Via `Post.php` model:

```php
$posts = Post::whereHas('animale', function ($query) {
  $query->where('animal', 'Dog');
})->get();
```

Either of these approaches will return a `Collection` of `Post` models that are related to the `Animal` model for `'Dog'`. The approach using `animal_id` in the other answer is valid, but only if you explicitly know the `animals.id` for `'Dog'` is `1`. If that changes, the query is completely invalid.

Answer (score 1):

It seems simple you just have to pass the dog id from the animal table.

```
$dog = Post::where('animal_id',1)->get();
```

or if you don't know about ID follow the below approach

```
$dog = Post::whereHas('animals', function ($query) {
           $query->where('animal', 'Dog');
        })->get();
```